# how to update the dataprovider of Amcharts by Input field values and query results

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, amcharts

I'm using serial type amchart and used query results in dataProvider. Now i need to change the dataProvider values according to the input values so i used another chart. But chart 2 not displayed anyone suggest me the solution to change the dataProvider values.

```js
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>

<script>
/**
 * Define universal config
 */
var chartConfig = {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "marginRight": 80,
  "dataProvider": [],
  "valueAxes": [{
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left",
    "title": "Send  count by each mailer "
  }],
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "<b>[[category]]: [[value]]</b>",
    "fillColorsField": "color",
    "fillAlphas": 0.9,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "customBulletField": "bullet",
    "bulletOffset": 10,
    "bulletSize": 52,
    "valueField": "visits"
  }],
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "categoryField": "country",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "labelRotation": 45
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
};

/**
 * Define function for cloning objects
 * Taken from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object
 */
function clone(obj) {
  var copy;

  // Handle the 3 simple types, and null or undefined
  if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;

  // Handle Date
  if (obj instanceof Date) {
    copy = new Date();
    copy.setTime(obj.getTime());
    return copy;
  }

  // Handle Array
  if (obj instanceof Array) {
    copy = [];
    for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++) {
      copy[i] = clone(obj[i]);
    }
    return copy;
  }

  // Handle Object
  if (obj instanceof Object) {
    copy = {};
    for (var attr in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = clone(obj[attr]);
    }
    return copy;
  }

  throw new Error("Unable to copy obj! Its type isn't supported.");
}

/**
 * Create first chart
 */

// create a copy of the universal config
var chartConfig1 = clone(chartConfig);

// modify a copy of the config
chartConfig1.dataProvider = [
<?php
$livemailersend="select t1.emp_id,t2.isp,t2.fname,t2.iurl,sum(t1.sent),sum(t1.opens) from red_global t1, admin_emp t2 where t1.emp_id=t2.emp_id and  t1.status_date between '$fromdate' and '$todate' and t1.emp_id  in (2010,2015,2016,2020,2022,2023,2025,2027)  group by 1,2,3,4 order by 5 desc;";
  $lmailersend_fetch=mysql_query($livemailersend,$link1);
  $color = array("#ccff33", "#ffcc00", "#ff9933","#ff33cc","#0099ff","#00ffcc","#00cc00","#0000cc","#6b616b","#a8a36b","#c5a6ff");
  $i=0;
  while($lmailersend=mysql_fetch_array($lmailersend_fetch))
  {
  echo" 
  {
    'country': '".$lmailersend[2]."(".round(($lmailersend[5]/$lmailersend[4])*100 , 2) ."%)',
    'visits': ".$lmailersend[4].",
    'color': '".$color[$i]."',
    'bullet': 'img/wxemp/".$lmailersend[3]."' 
  },";
  $i=$i+1;
  }?>
  ];

// create the chart
AmCharts.makeChart("chart1", chartConfig1);

/**
 * Create second chart
 */

// create a copy of the universal config
var chartConfig2 = clone(chartConfig);

// modify a copy of the config
chartConfig2.dataProvider = [
<?php
$livemailersend="select t1.emp_id,t2.isp,t2.fname,t2.iurl,sum(t1.sent),sum(t1.opens) from red_global t1, admin_emp t2 where t1.emp_id=t2.emp_id and  t1.status_date between '2017-05-18' and '2017-05-31' and t1.emp_id  in (2010,2015,2016,2020,2022,2023,2025,2027)  group by 1,2,3,4 order by 5 desc;";
  $lmailersend_fetch=mysql_query($livemailersend,$link1);
  $color = array("#ccff33", "#ffcc00", "#ff9933","#ff33cc","#0099ff","#00ffcc","#00cc00","#0000cc","#6b616b","#a8a36b","#c5a6ff");
  $i=0;
  while($lmailersend=mysql_fetch_array($lmailersend_fetch))
  {
  echo" 
  {
    'country': '".$lmailersend[2]."(".round(($lmailersend[5]/$lmailersend[4])*100 , 2) ."%)',
    'visits': ".$lmailersend[4].",
    'color': '".$color[$i]."',
    'bullet': 'img/wxemp/".$lmailersend[3]."' 
  },";
  $i=$i+1;
  }?>
  ];

// create the chart
AmCharts.makeChart("chart2", chartConfig2);
</script>
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

```html
<?php
$fromdate = date("Y-m-d");;
$todate = date("Y-m-d");;
$proteam = "yah";
//-----------------------datewise live report-------------------------------------//
$action =$_POST['action'];
$fromdatepick =$_POST['fromdatepick'];
$todatepick =$_POST['todatepick'];
if(($action)=="datewise")
{
echo($action. "<br/>".$fromdatepick. "<br/>".$todatepick. "<br/>");
}
?> 
<!-- BAR Chart -->
<div class="col-sm-12">
 <div id="bg-default" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
   <?php if(($action)!="datewise")
   {
   $where = ("and  t1.status_date between '$fromdate' and '$todate'");?>
    <div id="chart1" class="chartdiv" style="width : 100%; height : 500px;"></div>
   <?php } else {
   $where = ("and  t1.status_date between '$fromdatepick' and '$todatepick'");?>
   <div id="chart2" class="chartdiv" style="width : 100%; height : 500px;"></div>
            <?php } ?>     
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you already have the chart instance in the variable `chart`, you can do the following:

```
chart.dataProvider = [...]; // Change or replace the array
chart.validateData(); // Refreshes the chart based on the new data
```

[See more about validateData here](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#validateData)

Comment: it works for me when i use the static value in $fromdatepick and $todatepick but chart doesn't display when i use it as variable now i changed my code with reference to this https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/reusing-the-same-config-object-for-multiple-charts/ @Darlesson

Comment: Have in mind, if you are going to share the configuration from a variable in the client-side, you will need to do a deep clone of everything for each chart you are applying the configuration to.